# how to fix my phonebook code?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I am making a phonebook code that can add, delete specific phonenumbers, init the phonebook and print everything in the phonebook.

```
class contact:
name=""
number=""
def print_n(self):
    print("name : ", self.name)
    print("number : ",self.number)
def add():            #This is supposed to add names and numbers to contact
name = input("Name: ")
number = input("Number: ")
def init():          #This is supposed to initalize contact
 del contact
def s_delete():    #This is supposed to delete a phonenumber by typing in the person's name
s=input("name: ")
ss=input("number: ")
with contact:
    del s
    del ss
def print_all():    #This is supposed to print every phonenumber in the phonebook
print (contact)
```

that's how much I have gone so far. Is there something wrong in my code? Because it doesn't print the phonebook and doesn't add or delete any phone numbers.

Comment: Go read up on classes. You must define `__init__` first.

Comment: The immediate issue is the indentation in your question. Please fix that as this is a big blocker to be able to analyse the code further.

Comment: `def init():          #This is supposed to initalize contact` seems to be an oxymoron, since the only thing that `init()` tries to do is delete the contact? Also, `init()` is not the same as `__init__`. There's a lot of issues in this code.

Comment: Can you tell me the fixed version of my code?

Comment: That would require rewriting almost every single line. You need to go and read up about classes, and more broadly in python in general, to understand all of the issues you have here.

Comment: Then could you tell what 'invokes' means?

Comment: Calls a function/method? You haven't given any context, and the word doesn't appear in your question.

Comment: When a class defines an __init__() method, class instantiation automatically invokes __init__() for the newly-created class instance. from here

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not proper python. The class "contact" (python classes have first letters in upper case and are follow by `(object)` is not declared properly, init() should look like this `__init__` etc.

Does this code work for you:

```
class Phonebook(object):

    def print_n(self, name):
        print("%s: %s" % (name, self.contacts.get(name, "Does not exist")))


    #This is supposed to add names and numbers to contact
    def add(self, name, number): 
        self.contacts[name] = number

    #This is supposed to initalize contact
    def __init__(self):
        self.contacts = {}

    #This is supposed to delete a phonenumber by typing in the person's name
    def s_delete(self, name):
        del self.contacts[name]

    #This is supposed to print every phonenumber in the phonebook
    def print_all(self):
        for name in sorted(self.contacts.keys()):
        print('%s: %s' % (name, self.contacts[name]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
    action = input("Action (--add, -a; --delete, -d; --printall, -p; --exit, -e): ")
    if action in ['--add', '-a']:
        name = input("Name: ")
        number = input("Number: ")
        phonebook.add(name, number)
    elif action in ['--delete', '-d']:
        name = input("Name: ")
        phonebook.s_delete(name)
    elif action in ['--printall', '-p']:
        phonebook.print_all()
    elif action in ['--exit', '-e']:
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown action.")
```

Comment: I get a SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation at phonebook.add('foo', '1234')

Comment: python requires you to either use tabs or 4 space as indentation. if you mix them you get this error. the recommended approach here would be to backspace everything to the beginning of the line and then indent it by using 4 whitespaces, so you end up with it looking like the above code

Comment: I edited this answer using spaces, do you have tabs in your current code, @Arkady? Your indentation was incorrect in the initial post.

Comment: It should'nt have been tabs. I use vim and have it set up to replace tabs with spaces. Maybe I messed it up when I copied the code...

Comment: I'm not sure how the mismatch came about, that was only a thought. Your initial code, though, did not have any of the methods indented into the class body, so that's the change I made. In any case, you basically rewrote the OP's project, so I guess they need to track down the issue which is minor compared to the issues with the initial code.

Comment: Thanks for that. @Min Woo Kim, did that work for you?

Comment: It works. But if I want to ask the user to input the name and the number how do I do it? Like using input('name: ' ) and also delete numbers by asking the user.

Comment: I just added a simple while loop that should do what you asked.